# Using MAX(Time) and MAX(Date) to get only the latest per group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the latest highscore, per user, per game. My current query isn't working.

I have a SQL DB like the following:

```
player(string)  game(string)    score(int)  Date(Date)      time(Time)
jake            soccer          20          2016/02/26      10:00:00
jake            chess           50          2016/02/26      10:00:00
jake            soccer          40          2016/02/26      13:00:00
jake            chess           30          2016/02/26      13:00:00
jake            soccer          20          2016/02/26      15:00:00
jake            chess           60          2016/02/26      15:00:00
jake            soccer          80          2016/02/26      18:00:00
jake            chess           10          2016/02/26      18:00:00
mike            chess           30          2016/02/26      13:00:00
mike            soccer          20          2016/02/26      15:00:00
mike            chess           60          2016/02/26      15:00:00
mike            soccer          80          2016/02/26      18:00:00
mike            chess           10          2016/02/26      18:00:00
```

What I want to get out of it is:

```
jake            soccer          80          2016/02/26      18:00:00
jake            chess           10          2016/02/26      18:00:00
mike            soccer          80          2016/02/26      18:00:00
mike            chess           10          2016/02/26      18:00:00
```

I found out the Time column also has the date, so this should work.
This is my current Query:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM db t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT player, MAX(time) TS
    FROM db
    GROUP BY player
) t2 ON t2.player = t1.player and t2.TS = t1.time
ORDER BY score DESC";
```

EDIT: I'm getting lots of wrong rows. Basically. I'm getting them sorted by time, but not the date
I now need to sort them not only by MAX(Time) but MAX(Date) as well. Or merge Date and Time in a new var

Comment: Are you running it in the db or the application?It should work as it is.

Comment: That's weird I created a test with your example data and query. It works and you get the desired output.

Comment: My problem is with the Date after all.
I'm getting lots of rows for 23:59:00 and the dates of 2015, for example.
I need to sort by both MAX(Date) and MAX(Time).

Comment: What is the data type of [Time] column?

Comment: @gofr1 It's Time. I've also got a Date one

Comment: Replace time and ts in your query or my answer with that: convert(datetime,cast(date as nvarchar(10)) + ' '+ cast(time as nvarchar(10)))

Comment: @gofr1 not quite sure what to replace. Would you mind editing your answer to reflect the change?  Seems promising! Thanks!

Comment: @Carlos Miguel Fernando, I edited it!

Comment: @CarlosMiguelFernando hey, man, so, it helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the latest highscore, per user, per game, try this:

```
 ;WITH cte as (
 SELECT player, game, MAX(convert(datetime,cast([date] as nvarchar(10)) + ' '+ cast([time] as nvarchar(10)))) TS
 FROM db
 GROUP BY player, game)
 SELECT db.*
 FROM cte
 LEFT JOIN db ON cte.player = db.player and cte.game = db.game and cte.TS = convert(datetime,cast(db.[date] as nvarchar(10)) + ' '+ cast(db.[time] as nvarchar(10)))
 ORDER BY highscore DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This did it with only a couple minor bugs due to the DB being poorly built.
Eventually they added a DATETIME so now I just used MAX(DT) and it works like a charm!

Comment: Great! It's right approach to keep date and time in same column!

Answer (score 1):

Try using ROW_NUMBER()

```
SELECT
      t1.*
FROM (
      SELECT
            *
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY player ORDER BY [time] DESC) AS rn
      FROM db
      ) AS t1
WHERE rn = 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want not just the most recent game but also its score, this question can use the same patterns discussed here: [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/25534279)

Personally I think picking the most recent `time` and then using that to match rows in the outer query is a little scary, since someone just *might* have two games at the same instant. Also it won't give you the best performance. Depending on your RDBMS, the linked question might have better approaches.

Comment: I get what you're trying to say, but in this case this dB is just a mockup. My actual dB is similar bit it's about servers, drives and disk space. The query happens once every 2 minutes so there's no same time, only same dates